# gazebo window blinking

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

When I was trying to run Gazebo on Lucid 64bit, but the graphic window inside "Gazebo" window kept blinking.

Some information on my hardware:
My graphics card is ATI Integrated Radeon HD4200, which is listed as a working card in this link http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/SystemRequirements

I thought it was related to the graphic card driver. So I tried two ways to install the driver:

1. manually installed the latest driver ati-driver-installer-11-2-x86.x86_64
2. use "system"-"Administration"-"Hardware Drivers" and "activate" the default driver listed there.

But the problem still exist, still blinking. Any idea on this?

Thank you in advance.

Vincent

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9402/gazebo-window-blinking/) by [vincent](https://answers.ros.org/users/280/vincent/) on ROS Answers with karma: 311 on 2011-03-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can try disabling compiz, that should fix blinking.

---

Originally posted by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) with karma: 2121 on 2011-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vincent](https://answers.ros.org/users/280/vincent/) on 2011-03-14**:
Thank you, probably I will consider use Nvidia card, lol

**Comment by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) on 2011-03-13**:
That happens with AMD cards only, I suppose that's a driver "feature"... future driver revisions will probably fix this.

**Comment by [vincent](https://answers.ros.org/users/280/vincent/) on 2011-03-13**:
Yes that solved the problem~ Thanks a lot! So it's a conflict between compiz and gazebo?